# Comparing two text cells and show the differnce in third column in Excel sheet 2010/2007

Tags: excel

I want to compare two cells which contains text and show the difference in some colour

```
Ex:Cell A:NTR is a great Leader.
   Cell B:Ntr is a Great leader
```

Comment: Is it assumed that the text is the same but with different capitalization? If not, what do you output in the third cell, the difference from the first to the second or the difference from the second to the first?

Comment: Is the text always the same? If there is an added character in the middle this might be hard to detect.

Answer (score 3):

Using VBA.....

```
Sub CompareInColor()

ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

For i = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text <> 
        ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Characters(i, 1).Text) Then 
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next i

End Sub
```

This compares A1 and B1 only... Loop through your rows if you have many of them. Also, I assumed that the length of A1 and A2 is the same, otherwise an out-of-range index error may evolve.

Comment: +1 - Look so simple when someone else finds the answer. Well Done ;)

Comment: If you replace the second `C1` reference to `B1` you'll alter the colour in `B1` instead, eliminating the need for a third

Comment: @glh Agree... That would be even simpler!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CompareInColor()

ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

For i = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text <> ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Characters(i, 1).Text) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub CompareInColorFlip()

ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value

For i = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value)
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Characters(i, 1).Text <> ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This Compares A to B then changes font for differences in C and B to A then changes font for differences in D