# Identify/highlight changes of text parts in one cell

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I want to do the same as in [Comparing two text cells and show the differnce in third column in Excel sheet 2010/2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918931/comparing-two-text-cells-and-show-the-differnce-in-third-column-in-excel-sheet-2), but without the restriction that both text cells have the same length and same "word structure".

So assume a text cell A1 that contains some text:

"Lorem ipsum dolor est"

Now the user changes the text to

"Lorem tu sunt Ipsum est"

After that change, the text should be displayed as

"Lorem **tu sunt I**psum est"

I know I can change the format of text parts with something like `ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=9).Font`. But I am having trouble determining the changed parts, which brought me to the linked question.

I'm also aware of the "Track changes" feature of Excel. Unfortunately my text cells contain usually so much text that the popup that shows the change cannot show them completely. Also the changes are not shown with highlighting, but with old text and new text.

I also looked into changing the font color before the user starts editing in the text cell, but I was not able to write a macro that didn't change the font color of the whole text of the cell.

So the question is, how can I identify the text changes the user has made to a text cell? Alternatively, how can changes made in a text cell be highlighted?

Comment: To see the changes user done simply share your file. Would this be an alternative? https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared--workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61?CorrelationId=f3df4075-f5ee-439f-8376-ec8e3a52a885&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: @katz: Isn't that basically the "Track changes" feature? I already wrote in my question that it does not show the changes like it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet in `ThisWorkbook`:

`Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        TrackFile = "C:\temp\TRACKER.txt"
        TargUser = Application.UserName
        TargAddr = Sh.Name & "!" & Target.Address(False, False)
        TargVal = Target.Resize(1, 1).Text
        TargDate = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        x = TargDate & vbTab & TargUser & vbTab & TargAddr & vbTab & TargVal
        Open TrackFile For Append As #1
        Print #1, x
        Close #1
End Sub`

Any changes written to the .txt File with date, time, user, cell and text

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the tracking should be done in the Excel worksheet itself and not in another file. Also, it is required that the changed parts are highlighted.

Comment: so simply modify the snipped that the changes get written to an worksheet and then check letter by letter for the changed cells

Comment: I cannot compare letter by letter like in the linked question, because the texts usually do not have the same length. See the example in my question.